# javascript: How can find the location in screen/webpage to click

Tags: javascript, testing, web, automation

I need to build and automate task where I need to click a button in a web page but I don't know how can I get the location on screen. Any of you can be so kind and help me to figure out how to get position on screen to click ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are looking for, but `window.location.href` will give you the current URL

Comment: Let's say I want to click on the "Follow" buttons on pinterest page http://www.pinterest.com/zannywoonkie/followers/ . How can identify the location of the buttons to click on them.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Just by inspecting the button I see the button has a class name of 'UserFollowButton', so `document.getElementsByClassName('UserFollowButton')[0]` gives you a handle to the button. A little googling should get you the rest of the way there.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm trying to click on the buttons loading a page inside the javascript. I tried to use document.getElementsByClassName('UserFollowButton')[0] loading the webpage inside the javascript but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript function I wrote to simulate clicking a link. I think you can adapt it pretty easily to click any object in a page that has a valid ID:

```
function ClickLink(AnchorName) 
{              
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents"); 
    var Link = document.getElementById(AnchorName);

    var LinkForJquery = '#' + AnchorName

    var x = $(LinkForJquery).offset().left;
    var y = $(LinkForJquery).offset().top;

    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, x, y, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    var allowDefault = Link.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```